# Why is powershell so slow to validate huge byte[] arrays?

Tags: performance, powershell, parameter-passing

I've spent some time trying to find a bottleneck in a powershell application, without ever suspecting it was just a slow parameter validation. The sample code illustrates the problem:

```bsh
function Test-ValidatePerformance
{
    param(
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Byte[]]
        $Data
    )

    $sw.Stop()

    Write-Host "Executing after $([Math]::Round($sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliSeconds))ms"
}

function Test-NoValidatePerformance
{
    param(
        [Byte[]]
        $Data
    )

    $sw.Stop()

    Write-Host "Executing after $([Math]::Round($sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliSeconds))ms"
}

$buf = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('C:\17MB_FILE.bin')

Write-Host "Calling with validation..."
$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
Test-ValidatePerformance $buf

Write-Host "`nCalling without validation..."
$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
Test-NoValidatePerformance $buf
```

Output:

```
Calling with validation...
Executing after 1981ms

Calling without validation...
Executing after 3ms
```

My question is: Why is `[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]` so slow considering that (as its name states) it just checks for a null or empty parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add (most) validation attributes to a collection, it is applied to *each item* in the collection; not the collection as a whole, so that validation will be run against every individual byte.

[mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) brought up [an open issue on GitHub about this very thing](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6185).

The easiest way to test that it's not empty is just to make the parameter mandatory; an empty array won't be accepted then:

```
function Test-ValidatePerformance
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [Byte[]]
        $Data
    )

    $sw.Stop()

    Write-Host "Executing after $([Math]::Round($sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliSeconds))ms"
}
```

**Note:** as the original poster pointed out, and [Patrick Meinecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930135/patrick-meinecke) confirmed [in this GitHub issue, there is a bug in Windows PowerShell (fixed in Core), regarding the performance issue with Mandatory parameters](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5417).

If you want the parameter to be optional, but if supplied it must not be empty, you can use `[ValidateCount()]` instead, which should be quick:

```
function Test-ValidatePerformance
{
    param(
        [ValidateCount(1,[int]::MaxValue)]
        [Byte[]]
        $Data
    )

    $sw.Stop()

    Write-Host "Executing after $([Math]::Round($sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliSeconds))ms"
}
```

Or you can just do the check in code instead of using validation attributes.

```
function Test-ValidatePerformance
{
    param(
        [Byte[]]
        $Data
    )

    if (-not $Data -and $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Data')) {
        throw [System.ArgumentException]'An empty array is not allowed'
    }

    $sw.Stop()

    Write-Host "Executing after $([Math]::Round($sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliSeconds))ms"
}
```

Comment: Setting as mandatory caused it to be slower (2385ms), but `ValidateCount()` worked. Now I'm even more intrigued.

Comment: @karliwson hm that's interesting... I too am intrigued

Comment: @briantist: Interesting, indeed. Reminds me of https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6185

Comment: @karliwson That's a bug that was resolved in PowerShell core. For reference: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5417

Comment: Thanks to you both; I've linked those issues in the answer.

Comment: @PatrickMeinecke I suspected.. that was the only explanation.